# Late binding of COM->NET call with enum value argument(s)

Tags: .net, c++, com, binding, interop

First, note that this is just a learning exercise for me. The intent is to produce a .NET messagebox using nothing but pure C++ (not C++/CLI) and late binding as necessary.

This works fine with just a title and text in the messagebox.

However, when I try to specify buttons I get back 2147942487 "The parameter is incorrect". On the .NET side `MessageBox.Show` has this as an `enum` type argument. I am guessing that somehow the integer supplied as argument from C++, isn't automatically converted typewise.

I've tried to obtain an "object" of the enum type by calling `Enum.ToObject`. However, what's returned back to the COM/C++ side of things is just a `VARIANT` with type `I4`, i.e. a 32-bit integer.

Also, I've tried to Google this, but all I've found has been about how to obtain numerical values for .NET enum values. I have the numerical values. The problem *appears* to be how to get those numerical values automatically converted to enum-type arguments over in .NET?

However, *I could be totally wrong about what the problem is*.

So any help appreciated!

Code below (the hardcoded path will probably need adjustment on ur system):

```
/*
    // C# code that this C++ program should implement:
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace hello
    {
     class Startup
     {
      static void Main( string[] args )
      {
       MessageBox.Show(
        "Hello, world!",
        ".NET app:",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information
        );
      }
     }
    }
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>        // std::swap
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string>
using std::swap;

//#undef  UNICODE
//#define UNICODE
//#undef  NOMINMAX
//#define NOMINMAX
//#undef  STRICT
//#define STRICT
//#include <windows.h>

#include <Mscoree.h>
#include <comdef.h>
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF( ICorRuntimeHost, IID_ICorRuntimeHost );      // ICorRuntimeHostPtr

// #import is an MS extension, generates a header file. Will be replaced with #include.
#import "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v1.1.4322\\mscorlib.tlb" \
    raw_interfaces_only rename( "ReportEvent", "reportEvent" )

typedef mscorlib::_AppDomainPtr     AppDomainPtr;
typedef mscorlib::_AssemblyPtr      AssemblyPtr;
typedef mscorlib::_AssemblyNamePtr  AssemblyNamePtr;
typedef mscorlib::_MethodInfoPtr    MethodInfoPtr;
typedef mscorlib::_ObjectPtr        ObjectPtr;
typedef mscorlib::_TypePtr          TypePtr;


typedef ptrdiff_t   Size;
typedef Size        Index;

bool throwX( std::string const& s ) { throw std::runtime_error( s ); }


bool startsWith( wchar_t const prefix[], wchar_t const s[] )
{
    while( *prefix != 0 && *prefix == *s ) { ++prefix; ++s; }
    return (*prefix == 0);
}

template< class Predicate >
struct Is: Predicate
{};

template< class Type, class Predicate >
bool operator>>( Type const& v, Is< Predicate > const& check )
{
    return check( v );
}

struct HrSuccess
{
    bool operator()( HRESULT hr ) const
    {
        ::SetLastError( hr );
        return SUCCEEDED( hr );
    }
};

struct Text
{
private:
    std::ostringstream  stream;

    Text( Text const& );
    Text& operator=( Text const& );

public:
    Text() {}

    template< class Type >
    Text& operator<<( Type const& v )
    {
        stream << v;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string () const
    {
        return stream.str();
    }
};

template< class Type >
struct VariantType;

template<>
struct VariantType< IUnknown* >
{
    static VARENUM const    id  = VT_UNKNOWN;
};

template<>
struct VariantType< VARIANT >
{
    static VARENUM const    id  = VT_VARIANT;
};

class OleVector
{
private:
    typedef OleVector   ThisClass;
    SAFEARRAY*  descriptor_;
    Index       lowerBound_;
    Index       upperBound_;

    ThisClass( ThisClass const& );
    ThisClass& operator=( ThisClass const& );

    Index lowerBound() const
    {
        if( descriptor_ == 0 ) { return 0; }
        long result;
        SafeArrayGetLBound( descriptor_, 1, &result )
            >> Is< HrSuccess >()
            || throwX( "OleVector::lowerBound: SafeArrayGetLBound failed" );
        return result;
    }

    Index upperBound() const
    {
        if( descriptor_ == 0 ) { return 0; }
        long result;
        SafeArrayGetUBound( descriptor_, 1, &result )
            >> Is< HrSuccess >()
            || throwX( "OleVector::upperBound: SafeArrayGetUBound failed" );
        return result;
    }

public:
    OleVector(): descriptor_( 0 ) {}

    explicit OleVector( SAFEARRAY* descriptor )
        : descriptor_( descriptor )
        , lowerBound_( 0 )
        , upperBound_( 0 )
    {
        assert( descriptor_ == 0 || ::SafeArrayGetDim( descriptor_ ) == 1 );
        lowerBound_ = lowerBound();
        upperBound_ = upperBound();
    }

    template< class ElemType >
    OleVector( Size size, VariantType< ElemType > )
        : descriptor_( ::SafeArrayCreateVector( VariantType< ElemType >::id, 0, size ) )
        , lowerBound_( 0 )
        , upperBound_( size - 1 )
    {
        assert( descriptor_ != 0 && ::SafeArrayGetDim( descriptor_ ) == 1 );
        lowerBound_ = lowerBound();
        upperBound_ = upperBound();
    }

    ~OleVector()
    {
        if( descriptor_ != 0 )
        {
            ::SafeArrayDestroy( descriptor_ );
        }
    }

    SAFEARRAY* asSafeArray() const
    {
        return descriptor_;
    }

    VARENUM elemType() const
    {
        VARTYPE     result  = 0;
        if( descriptor_ != 0 )
        {
            ::SafeArrayGetVartype( descriptor_, &result )
                >> Is< HrSuccess >()
                || throwX( "OleVector::elemType: SafeArrayGetVartype failed" );
        }
        return VARENUM( result );
    }

    void swapWith( OleVector& other )
    {
        swap( descriptor_, other.descriptor_ );
        swap( lowerBound_, other.lowerBound_ );
        swap( upperBound_, other.upperBound_ );
    }

    void clear()
    {
        OleVector().swapWith( *this );
    }

    Size count() const
    {
        return (upperBound_ + 1) - lowerBound_;
    }

    Size elemSize() const
    {
        return (descriptor_ == 0? 0 : ::SafeArrayGetElemsize( descriptor_ ));
    }

    void getElement( Index i, void* pResult ) const
    {
        long internalIndex  = i + lowerBound_;
        ::SafeArrayGetElement( descriptor_, &internalIndex, pResult )
            >> Is< HrSuccess >()
            || throwX( "OleVector::getElement: SafeArrayGetElement failed" );
    }

    void setElement( Index i, void* pData )
    {
        long internalIndex  = i + lowerBound_;
        ::SafeArrayPutElement( descriptor_, &internalIndex, pData )
            >> Is< HrSuccess >()
            || throwX( "OleVector::setElement: SafeArrayPutElement failed" );
    }
};

template< class ElemType >
class ElemAccess
{
private:
    OleVector*  v_;

    template< class T >
    static void* safeArrayPutArg( T& v ) { return &v; }

    template<>
    static void* safeArrayPutArg( IUnknown*& v ) { return v; }

public:
    ElemAccess( OleVector& v )
        : v_( &v )
    {
        assert( VariantType< ElemType >::id == v_->elemType() );
        assert( v_->elemSize() == sizeof( ElemType ) );
    }

    ElemType elem( Index i ) const
    {
        ElemType    result;
        v_->getElement( i, &result );
        return result;
    }

    void setElem( Index i, ElemType v )
    {
        v_->setElement( i, safeArrayPutArg( v ) );
    }
};


void cppMain()
{
    ICorRuntimeHostPtr  pCorRuntimeHost;
    CorBindToRuntimeEx(
        L"v1.1.4322",         // LPWSTR pwszVersion,  // RELEVANT .NET VERSION.
        L"wks",                 // LPWSTR pwszBuildFlavor, // "wks" or "svr"
        0,                      // DWORD flags,
        CLSID_CorRuntimeHost,   // REFCLSID rclsid,
        IID_ICorRuntimeHost,    // REFIID riid,
        reinterpret_cast<void**>( &pCorRuntimeHost )
        )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "CorBindToRuntimeEx failed" );

    pCorRuntimeHost->Start()    // Without this GetDefaultDomain fails.
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "CorRuntimeHost::Start failed" );

    IUnknownPtr     pAppDomainIUnknown;
    pCorRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain( &pAppDomainIUnknown )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "CorRuntimeHost::GetDefaultDomain failed" );

    AppDomainPtr    pAppDomain  = pAppDomainIUnknown;
    (pAppDomain != 0)
        || throwX( "Obtaining _AppDomain interface failed" );

    AssemblyPtr     pCoreLibAssembly;
    {
        SAFEARRAY*  rawAssembliesArray;
        pAppDomain->GetAssemblies( &rawAssembliesArray )
            >> Is< HrSuccess >()
            || throwX( "_AppDomain::GetAssemblies failed" );

        OleVector   assemblies( rawAssembliesArray );
        Size const  n       = assemblies.count();

        std::cout << n << " assemblies loaded." << std::endl;
        if( n > 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "Array elemtype " << assemblies.elemType() << "." << std::endl;

            ElemAccess< IUnknown* >     elems( assemblies );
            for( Index i = 0;  i < n;  ++i )
            {
                IUnknownPtr         pUnknown( elems.elem( i ) );
                AssemblyPtr         pAssembly( pUnknown );

                _bstr_t     displayName;
                pAssembly->get_ToString( displayName.GetAddress() )
                    >> Is< HrSuccess >()
                    || throwX( "_Assembly::get_ToString failed" );
                std::cout
                    << i + 1 << ": "
                    << "\"" << displayName.operator char const*() << "\""
                    << std::endl;
                if( startsWith( L"mscorlib,", displayName ) )
                {
                    pCoreLibAssembly = pAssembly;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    (pCoreLibAssembly != 0)
        || throwX( "mscorlib was not loaded by the .NET initialization" );

    TypePtr     pStringType;
    pCoreLibAssembly->GetType_2( _bstr_t( L"System.String" ), &pStringType )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::GetType failed (for System.String)" );
    (pStringType != 0 )
        || throwX( "System.String type not found" );

    TypePtr     pEnumType;
    pCoreLibAssembly->GetType_2( _bstr_t( L"System.Enum" ), &pEnumType )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::GetType failed (for System.Enum)" );
    (pEnumType != 0 )
        || throwX( "System.Enum type not found" );

    AssemblyPtr     pFormsAssembly;
    pAppDomain->Load_2( _bstr_t( L"System.Windows.Forms, Version=1.1.4322.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" ), &pFormsAssembly )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "Loading System.Windows.Forms assembly failed" );
    std::cout << "Loaded the System.Windows.Forms assembly." << std::endl;

    _bstr_t     formsAssemblyDisplayName;
    pFormsAssembly->get_ToString( formsAssemblyDisplayName.GetAddress() )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::get_ToString failed" );
    std::cout << "\"" << formsAssemblyDisplayName.operator char const*() << "\"" << std::endl;

    TypePtr     pMessageBoxButtonsType;
    pFormsAssembly->GetType_2( _bstr_t( L"System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons" ), &pMessageBoxButtonsType )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::GetType failed (for System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons)" );
    (pMessageBoxButtonsType != 0 )
        || throwX( "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons type not found" );

    TypePtr     pMessageBoxIconType;
    pFormsAssembly->GetType_2( _bstr_t( L"System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon" ), &pMessageBoxIconType )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::GetType failed (for System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon)" );
    (pMessageBoxIconType != 0 )
        || throwX( "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon type not found" );

    TypePtr     pMessageBoxType;
    pFormsAssembly->GetType_2( _bstr_t( L"System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox" ), &pMessageBoxType )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_Assembly::GetType failed" );
    (pMessageBoxType != 0 )
        || throwX( "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox type not found" );


    Size const  nArgs = 2;      // With 3 args (3rd is a button spec), the invocation fails.

    OleVector                   argTypesVec( nArgs, VariantType< IUnknown* >() );
    ElemAccess< IUnknown*>      argTypes( argTypesVec );
    argTypes.setElem( 0, static_cast<IUnknown*>( pStringType ) );
    argTypes.setElem( 1, static_cast<IUnknown*>( pStringType ) );
    if( nArgs > 2 ) { argTypes.setElem( 2, static_cast<IUnknown*>( pMessageBoxButtonsType ) ); }
    if( nArgs > 3 ) { argTypes.setElem( 3, static_cast<IUnknown*>( pMessageBoxIconType ) ); }

    MethodInfoPtr   pShowMethod;
    pMessageBoxType->GetMethod_5(
        _bstr_t( L"Show" ), argTypesVec.asSafeArray(), &pShowMethod
        )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "MessageBox::GetMethod failed for method Show" );

    _bstr_t     showMethodDescription;
    pShowMethod->get_ToString( showMethodDescription.GetAddress() )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( "_MethodInfo::get_ToString failed" );
    std::cout << "MethodInfo: \"" << showMethodDescription.operator char const*() << "\"" << std::endl;

    _variant_t      okButtonIdAsVariant;



    //OleVector               toObjectArgsVec( 2, VariantType< VARIANT >() );
    //ElemAccess< VARIANT >   toObjectArgs( toObjectArgsVec );

    //toObjectArgs.setElem( 0, _variant_t( static_cast<IUnknown*>( pMessageBoxButtonsType ) ).GetVARIANT() );
    //toObjectArgs.setElem( 1, _variant_t( MB_OKCANCEL ) );
    //pEnumType->InvokeMember_3(
    //    _bstr_t( L"ToObject" ),
    //    mscorlib::BindingFlags(
    //        mscorlib::BindingFlags_Public | mscorlib::BindingFlags_Static | mscorlib::BindingFlags_InvokeMethod
    //        ),
    //    0,      // Binder
    //    _variant_t(), //targetObject.GetVARIANT(),
    //    toObjectArgsVec.asSafeArray(),
    //    &okButtonIdAsVariant
    //    )
    //    >> Is< HrSuccess >()
    //    || throwX( Text() << "_Type::InvokeMember failed, member = ToObject, code = " << GetLastError() );

    //ObjectPtr   pOkButtonId( okButtonIdAsVariant );   // The variant is just I4 with the id value.

    _variant_t              targetObject( static_cast< IUnknown* >( pMessageBoxType ) );
    _variant_t              result;
    OleVector               argsVec( nArgs, VariantType< VARIANT >() );
    ElemAccess< VARIANT >   args( argsVec );

    args.setElem( 0, _variant_t( L"Hello, world!" ).GetVARIANT() );
    args.setElem( 1, _variant_t( L"C++ app using .NET:" ).GetVARIANT() );
    if( nArgs > 2 ) { args.setElem( 2, _variant_t( MB_OK ) ); }
    if( nArgs > 3 ) { args.setElem( 3, _variant_t( MB_ICONINFORMATION ) ); }
    std::cout << argsVec.count() << " args." << std::endl;

    //pMessageBoxType->InvokeMember_3(
    //    _bstr_t( L"Show" ),
    //    mscorlib::BindingFlags(
    //        mscorlib::BindingFlags_Public | mscorlib::BindingFlags_Static | mscorlib::BindingFlags_InvokeMethod
    //        ),
    //    0,      // Binder
    //    _variant_t(), //targetObject.GetVARIANT(),
    //    argsVec.asSafeArray(),
    //    &result
    //    )
    //    >> Is< HrSuccess >()
    //    || throwX( Text() << "_Type::InvokeMember failed, code = " << GetLastError() );

    pShowMethod->Invoke_3( targetObject.GetVARIANT(), argsVec.asSafeArray(), &result )
        >> Is< HrSuccess >()
        || throwX( Text() << "MethodInfo::Invoke failed for MessageBox::Show, code = " << GetLastError() );

    std::cout << "Result type " << result.vt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( std::exception const& x )
    {
        std::cerr << "!" << x.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is, and I can't try out your code because I don't have C++ or .Net 1.1 on my machine. Does passing the result of `Enum.ToObject` return the same error as just passing in `MB_OK`? Does changing the version of the framework change anything?

Comment: @Gabe: thanks for looking into it. Yes, same error, because `Enum.ToObject` just returns an integer to the C++ side. .NET 4.0 works OK (for two arguments) by replacing "1.1.4322" with "4.0.30319". However, without a C++ compiler presumably it doesn't work... :-)  Cheers,

Comment: @Gabe: re "Does changing the version of the framework change anything?" It certaingly DOES! Four args works OK with .NET 4.0! Now I haven't checked .NET 3.5 or 2.0, exactly where this was fixed, but if you write that comment up as an answer I'll tick it as "the" correct answer... Thank you! Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're invoking an older version of the .Net framework (v1.1 is over 7 years old), and I suspect that its marshalling or method binding is a bit restrictive. The versions I tested (v2.0, v4.0) let me just pass an int for any enum types to `Invoke`, which should be sufficient for your little test.