# How to "box" a value WITHOUT using programming language's boxing support?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

I want to box a value without using whatever .NET language's built-in support for that.

That is, given an enum value I want an reference type object that represents that value and its type.

This is a subgoal of being able to pass enum values from late binding pure C++ code, a possible solution of that, so, I'm not looking for how to use e.g. C# boxing (that's easy, and irrelevant in so many ways).

The following code yields ...

```
c:\projects\test\csharp\hello\main.cs(6,26): error CS0122: 'System.Reflection.RuntimeFieldInfo' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

However, using the more documented `FieldInfo` class, which is what the signature of `MakeTypedReference` requires, I get an exception saying that the argument isn't `RuntimeFieldInfo`.

The unsuccessful code, experimental, C#:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Type = System.Type;
using TypedReference = System.TypedReference;
using MethodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodInfo;
using FieldInfo = System.Reflection.FieldInfo;
using RuntimeFieldInfo = System.Reflection.RuntimeFieldInfo;

namespace hello
{
    class Startup
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Type        stringType      = typeof( string );
            Type        messageBoxType  = typeof( MessageBox );
            Type        mbButtonsType   = typeof( MessageBoxButtons );
            Type        mbIconType      = typeof( MessageBoxIcon );
            Type[]      argTypes        = { stringType, stringType, mbButtonsType };// }, mbIconType };
            MethodInfo  showMethod      = messageBoxType.GetMethod( "Show", argTypes );

//          object      mbOkBtn         = (object) (MessageBoxButtons) (0);
            TypedReference tr           = TypedReference.MakeTypedReference(
                mbButtonsType,
                new RuntimeFieldInfo[]{ mbIconType.GetField( "OK" ) }
                );
            object      mbOkBtn         = TypedReference.ToObject( tr );

            object[]    mbArgs          = { "Hello, world!", "Reflect-app:", mbOkBtn };

            showMethod.Invoke( null, mbArgs );
        }
    }
}
```

An answer that helps making the above code "work" would be very nice.

An answer that points out another way to achieve boxing (perhaps the above is completely and utterly wrong? - it's just experimental) would also be very nice! :-)

**EDIT**: Clarification: essentially I'm after the same as C# `(object)v` yields. I have tried the enum `ToObject` method, but unfortunately while that presumably works OK within .NET, on the C++ side I just get back the 32-bit integer value. The problem on the C++ side is that passing an integer as third arg of e.g. `MessageBox.Show` just fails, presumably because the default binder on the .NET side doesn't convert it to enum type, so I suspect a reference object of suitable type is needed for actual argument.

Comment: I am puzzled by your namespace aliases

Comment: To get it to compile, just change `new RuntimeFieldInfo[]` to `new []` and delete the `using RuntimeFieldInfo` -- unfortunately that won't help because the result of `GetField()` doesn't work in the `MakeTypedReference` function. :(

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You are trying to write code in C# to box values, yet you don't want C# code to do the boxing? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Gabe: it's necessary to use a concrete language to explore things. :-) The language doesn't matter.

Comment: Alf: You should post the C++ code that isn't working, because you should be able to pass an integer to any function expecting an enum. C# is strict about converting between enums and ints, but the CLR mostly doesn't care.

Comment: @Game: I've already posted [the C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007496/late-binding-of-com-net-call-with-enum-value-arguments) in another SO question (I've answered about 121 questions and asked 3, none of the 3 asked have been resolved, but perhaps this one will be the first!)

Comment: Alf: OK, I've commented on your other question, because I don't think this is the road you want to go down.

Comment: Over at the other question @Gabe asked whether the version of .NET mattered. And it turns out that with .NET 4.0, as opposed to .NET 1.1, passing integers from C++ works for enum type formal arguments. So, main problem solved. :-) This sub-problem is however still interesting, I think...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure exactly what sort of boxing you want, but if you want a `TypedReference`, just use `__makeref()` in C#. Here's a working version of your program:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using MethodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodInfo;

namespace hello
{
    class Startup
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type stringType = typeof(string);
            Type messageBoxType = typeof(MessageBox);
            Type mbButtonsType = typeof(MessageBoxButtons);
            Type[] argTypes = { stringType, stringType, mbButtonsType };
            MethodInfo showMethod = messageBoxType.GetMethod("Show", argTypes);

            var OkBtn = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            TypedReference tr = __makeref(OkBtn);
            object mbOkBtn = TypedReference.ToObject(tr);

            object[] mbArgs = { "Hello, world!", "Reflect-app:", mbOkBtn };

            showMethod.Invoke(null, mbArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new! :-) However it's still an intrinsic, isn't it? I'll try to delve into it, but I'm really after some language-independent way that I can use from a pure not-.NET not-C++/CLI pure standard C++ program. It is for learning purposes. Hence the upvote, I learned! :-) Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the hidden keyword  '__makeref' rather than TypedReference.MakeTypedReference

```
var v = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
var tr = __makeref(v);
var obj = TypedReference.ToObject(tr);
var s = obj.ToString();

//  s = "OK"
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new. :-) see my comment to @Gabe.

Answer (score 0):

Any routine that can take something of type `Object` could be used to store value types, without employing the Framework's boxing support, by creating a single-element array for each value-type instance to be stored, and storing a reference to that.  Compilers could support things like `Debug.Print` which need to accept a variable number of arbitrary-type parameters by having a special declaration which would request that the compiler pass a `System.Array[]`, each element of which would be a single-element array that wrapped a single parameter without regard for whether it was a class type or value type.  If such support existed, it would be possible for the `Debug.Print` routine to know the storage-location type of each parameter as well as the type of the object instance therein (e.g. in code like

```
Cat Meowser = new SiameseCat();
Animal Ralph = new PersianCat();
IPettable Mindy = new MixedBreedCat();
Debug.Print("{0:T} {1:T} {2:T}", Meowser, Ralph, Mindy);
```

the `Debug.Print` routine would receive a `System.Array[3]` holding references to a `Cat[1]`, an `Animal[1]`, and an `IPettable[1]`.

Note that without boxing support, structures that implement interfaces could not be inherently cast directly to interface references; this would sometimes be a limitation, but imposing that limitation could make it possible for value types to define conversions to and from interface types.  If desired, a compiler could auto-define a class type for each struct type that implements an interface and define conversions between the struct type and that interface type.  Such a thing effectively happens with the type system except that the reference type associated with each value type is generated at run-time rather than by the compiler.